# Separation of variables: When can we say that a function of $x$ and $t$ (for example) is a function of $x$ times a function of $t$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, differential-equations

I've seen this a lot in physics so far. For example in the stationary state solution to the Schrodinger equation for hydrogenic atoms, it's commonly approached using $\psi(r,\theta,\phi)=R(r)\Theta(\theta)\Phi(\phi)$. Another example is used in splitting the Schrodinger equation into time-dependent and time-independent parts, wherein we commonly claim $\Psi(\vec{r},t)=\psi(\vec{r})\psi(t)$. But I know not every equation can be broken down this way. For example, if $F(x,y)=x+y$, we can't say that $F(x,y)=f(x)f(y)$ because such two functions don't exist. So when can we do this kind of breaking down? Not just from a mathematical perspective (like the one I just showed), but from a physics interpretation? I know in quantum mechanics, we can usually assume a breakdown like this when there are stationary states, but I'm looking for a more general/conceptual idea...

Comment: This separation of variables is useful when solving PDEs. But as you know, not every function can be written as such. I don't know if one can really say anything more than that.

Comment: Actually, for Hamilton-Jacobi equations, the "classical version" (i.e. eikonal approximation) of Schrödinger, you do look for additive separation of variables instead of a multiplicative one.

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea is summarized in the following simple example:

Assume we have the following differential equation
$$(\frac{d}{dx} + \frac{d}{dy})\psi (x,y) = \alpha \psi (x,y),$$
where $\alpha$ is some arbitrary constant (independent of $x$ and $y$).
Since the differential equation does not contain any differential operator that mixes up (couples) $x$ and $y$ differentiations, you can always write the following decoupled ansatz:
$$  \psi (x,y) = f (x) g(y), $$
and factorize $\alpha$ to $\alpha = \alpha_f + \alpha_g$, where $f(x)$ and $\alpha_f$ solve
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=\alpha_f f(x),$$
and $g(x)$ and $\alpha_g$ solve
$$\frac{d}{dx}g(x)=\alpha_g g(x).$$

In the spherically symmetric potential case ($V=V(r)$), the Schrödinger equation reads:
$$\left[-\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m}\frac{1}{r^{2}}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^{2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)+\frac{1}{\sin\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\left(\sin\theta\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\right)+\frac{1}{\sin^{2}\theta}\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial\varphi^{2}}\right)+V(r)\right]\psi(r,\theta,\varphi)=E\psi(r,\theta,\varphi),$$ and the fact that partial differential operators do not mix spherical variables already indicates that separation of the three variables can be already achieved. Your function $F(x,y)=x+y$ does not solve a differential equation of a similar structure to these equations, and therefore the reasoning made here cannot be made there.

Answer (score 0):

The physical meaning of separability is that a function $f(x,t)$ is separable if  for arbitrary times $t_1$ and $t_2$ the curves $y_{t_1}(x) = f(x,t_1)$ and $y_{t_2}(x) = f(x,t_2)$ are identical up to a multiplicative constant which may depend on $t_1$ and $t_2$. In other words, the ratio

$\displaystyle \frac {f(x,t_1)}{f(x,t_2)}$

is independent of $x$ (although it may depend on $t_1$ and $t_2$).

Alternatively, we can pick arbitrary positions $x_1$ and $x_2$ and see if the curves $y_{x_1}(t) = f(x_1,t)$ and $y_{x_2}(t) = f(x_2,t)$ are identical up to a multiplicative constant, or in other words

$\displaystyle \frac {f(x_1,t)}{f(x_2,t)}$

is independent of $t$.

Answer (score 0):

Browsing through Math.SE, I found [this question and its answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/575205/648911) (and links therein) to be the most informative. Because of the applicability of the method to many physical problems, the answers there are not just about the mathematics of PDEs. Mathematically, there are some PDEs for which the separation of variables technique can "work" (i.e., solutions can be found in that form, and there are uniqueness theorems for the solutions of those equations that guarantee that solution to be *the* solution).  But from what I see there, there is not a general theory on how determine if a separable solution exists for a given PDE.

The answer by Willie Wong to the question linked above links to a book by Willard Miller: [*Symmetry and Separation of Variables*](https://www-users.cse.umn.edu/%7Emille003/separationofvariables.html), 1977).  He begins Chapter 1 with this:

> The main ideas relating the symmetry group of a linear partial differential equation and the coordinate systems in which the equation admits separable solutions are most easily understood through examples.

So there is a connection between the symmetries of the equation, the choice of coordinates to best elucidate those symmetries, and the existence of a separable solution to the equation *in those coordinates*.

So, for example, with the Hydrogen atom, once could express the Schrodinger equation as:
$$
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu} \left( \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} \right) \psi(x,y,z) + V(x,y,z)\, \psi(x,y,z) = E \, \psi(x,y,z)
$$
but one would not expect to find solutions of the form: $\psi(x,y,z)= X(x) Y(y) Z(z)$.  Only when you express that equation in spherical coordinates do you take advantage of the symmetry of the potential, $V(x,y,z) = V(r)$, and only in spherical coordinates can you expect a separable solution.

Answer (score 0):

A separable function has a certain kind of symmetry to it. This symmetry is useful in various physics problems. Some examples might best get the idea across.

Suppose you have a light source that produces a steady spherically symmetric light. If you look in a particular direction at a particular instant, you can describe the intensity with $I = R(r)$, where $R(r) \propto 1/r^2$. If you look at a later time or a different direction, you see the same function. So you could describe it with $I = R(r)\Theta(\theta)\Phi(\phi)T(t)$, where $\Theta(\theta) = \Phi(\phi) = T(t) = 1$.

Suppose you added an absorber so the intensity was half as bright on one side.
an expanding spherical light pulse. Then you would still see $R(r) \propto 1/r^2$ in any direction you pick. But now $\Theta(\theta) = 1$ when $0 < \theta <\pi$, and $1/2$ otherwise.

Suppose the light fades out. You might find that $T(t) \propto e^{-kt}$. There would still be an inverse square dependence on $r$ in any direction. The intensity would still be half as bright in one hemisphere.

An example that does not separate this way would be if the light was steady, but the absorber got darker with time. In the hemisphere where $0 < \theta < \pi$, $T(t) = 1$. In the other $T(t) = e^{-kt}$.

You could make a function, call it $\Theta T(\theta,t)$, where $I = R(r)\Theta T(\theta, t)\Phi(\phi)$. But you could not separate $\Theta T$ into $\Theta(\theta)T(t)$.